# follow mouse x on mouse over createjs

Tags: createjs

I have a graphic within a clip

what I'm trying to do is: 
when the mouse is over the parent clip I want the graphic to move/follow the direction of the mouse,
What I have so far

```
exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.addEventListener("mouseover",function (evt) {

var _this = evt.target.arrowYou
console.log(evt.target.arrowYou)
var mouseRight = 0;
var mouseLeft = 180;

 var offset = {x: _this.x - evt.stageX, y: _this.y - evt.stageY};

 evt.target.arrowYou.addEventListener("mousemove" , function(ev){
// )

 var pt = exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)

  if ( pt.y > mouseLeft){
    percent = 100;
} else if (pt.y < mouseRight){
    percent = 0;
} else {

    percent = Math.round(((pt.y - mouseRight) / (mouseLeft - mouseRight)*100));
_this.y = pt.y; 


}
 if ( pt.y > mouseLeft){ 

 }


setWheels(percent)


   })

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Rather than putting the function in a an eventlistener I placed it in the tick function.
tracked the mouseX with globalToLocal and set the nested graphic to that

```
function controlArrows(){
  if(gameStarted == true){
    var mouseRight = 0;
    var mouseLeft = 180;
    var arrowAwdY = exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.awd.arrowAWD.y
percentAWD  = Math.round(((arrowAwdY) / (180)*100))
    var pt = exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)
 if (pt.y > mouseLeft){
    percent = 100;
    } else if (pt.y < mouseRight){
    percent = 0;
    } else {
 percent = Math.round(((pt.y - mouseRight) / (mouseLeft - mouseRight)*100));
 exportRoot.game_anim.meterMC.arrowYou.y = pt.y;    
 setWheels(percent)
      }
   }    
}
```